# How to count the number of times a website is visited and the number of online users in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to find out the number of times a website has been visited and how many online users it has.

My code is this:

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        // Code that runs on application startup
        Application["SiteVisitedCounter"] = 0;
        //to check how many users have currently opened our site write the following line
        Application["OnlineUserCounter"] = 0;
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        Application.Lock();
        Application["SiteVisitedCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["SiteVisitedCounter"]) + 1;
        //to check how many users have currently opened our site write the following line
        Application["OnlineUserCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["OnlineUserCounter"]) + 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends.
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
        Application.Lock();
        Application["OnlineUserCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["OnlineUserCounter"]) - 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }
```

The HomeController class contains the following code.
I got an error on System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.

```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.noofsitesvisited = "No of times site visited=" + System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application["SiteVisitedCounter"].ToString();
        ViewBag.onlineusers = "No of users online on the site=" + System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application["OnlineUserCounter"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you filter out webcrawlers to find actual human visitors.

Comment: Yep. Good point @AdamHeeg. Anything you do like this is counting *requests*, not actual live human beings. Yet another reason to use real analytics tracking software, and forgo the roll-your-own approach.

Comment: @Adam Heeg Very Good Point.Can you suggest me how to do so

Comment: I did an implementation of this once, but even then it wasn't perfect.  There is a list of common crawler and bot names that you can get and then you would have to parse the request information for any matches.  It isn't perfect at all and I did it 4 years ago.  I cannot give you any specifics.

Comment: @AdamHeeg i think i have to change this question as how to find actual human visitors. may i get more information.what do you suggest dear

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have much more information to give you.  I don't have sample code and I don't do web work anymore.  Best of luck.

Comment: @Manraj please post your new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do it this way. One, reading and writing data from anything global in web environment is dangerous and inadvisable from the get go, and two, this will only store the count while the AppPool is active anyways. If the server restarts or the AppPool restarts or even just recycles, your counts all go away and you start over from zero.

If you want to store a count that needs to persist, then you need to use a persistent medium: database, text file, etc. Not only is this safer in general, it is also the only way to have a true persistent count.

That said, why not just use Google Analytics or some other form of website analytics. Not only are you reinventing the wheel, but actual analytics tracking will be more accurate and provide more useful statistics than anything you can do on your own.

Comment: Dear if i save these viewbagvalues to my db at index[Http] and check viewbag value is greater than db value. What will you suggest?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand.

Comment: if i save the value of visited users in database and check the Current ViewBag value is greater then it save the value in database field but if not then it has to use the value of database and set for Viewbag in this current  context. Any suggestion help me a lot

Comment: Just read and write directly to/from the database. It's always going to be your source of truth. You'll need to account for concurrency, but ultimately you shouldn't be comparing anything to anything. Just increment the value in your database for each visit, and read directly from the database to display the current count.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code in the controller as follows:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.noofsitesvisited = "No of times site visited=" + HttpContext.Application["SiteVisitedCounter"].ToString();
        ViewBag.onlineusers = "No of users online on the site=" + HttpContext.Application["OnlineUserCounter"].ToString();
    }
```

In MVC Application variables are accessible via HttpContext

Comment: can you tell me why No of times site visited and No of users online on the site are same that is now i facing problem

Comment: Thanks for help. +1 to you